# Server side paging and per-column filtering in SQL server with minimal dynamic SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Goal:** Write an STP for SQL Server 2012+ that can do server-side paging and per-column filtering, returning the row count of the unfiltered and filtered data, with as little dynamic SQL as possible.

---

**Motivation:** We have many queries for our website that would return thousands of rows, so server-side paging is needed. The results from these queries are displayed in large tables which allow for ordering on a single column and filtering on multiple columns, which is different from many solutions I've seen online which have a single search field for the whole table. Additionally, we need the total size of the unfiltered and filtered resultset to display to the user as `Showing 1-10 of 2,500 (filtered from 15,000)`.

Our current method to achieve this is with a query defined as:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[stp_MyBigQuery] 
    @take INT = 25,
    @skip INT = 0,
    @sortBy VARCHAR(256) = 'Name',
    @sortDir VARCHAR(5) = 'desc',
    @searchBy NVARCHAR(max) = ''
AS BEGIN
    DECLARE @sql varchar(max) = '
        ;WITH fullList AS ( SELECT Name, Age, Town FROM MyBigTable ),
        totalCount AS ( SELECT COUNT(*) AS numRows FROM fullList )
        SELECT
            fl.*,
            COUNT(*) over() as filteredCount,
            (select top 1 totalCount.numRows from totalCount) as totalCount
        INTO #temp
        from fullList fl'

    IF(@searchBy != '') BEGIN
        SET @sql = @sql + ' WHERE ' + @searchBy + ' '
    END

    SET @sql = @sql + ' ORDER BY ' + @sortBy + ' ' + @sortDir + 
        ' OFFSET ' + CAST(@skip AS varchar(32)) + ' rows ' +
        'fetch next ' + CAST(@take AS varchar(32)) + ' rows only '

    SET @sql = @sql + '
        declare @total bigint = (SELECT TOP 1 totalCount FROM #temp)
        declare @filteredCount bigint = (SELECT TOP 1 filteredCount FROM #temp)

        ALTER TABLE #temp
        DROP COLUMN filteredCount, totalCount

        SELECT
            t.*
        FROM #temp t
        ORDER BY ' + @sortBy + ' ' + @sortDir + ' 

        SELECT ISNULL(@filteredCount,0)
        SELECT ISNULL(@total,0)

        DROP TABLE #temp'
    exec(@sql)
END
```

Where `@searchBy` would be something like `Name ='Alice' and Age > 30`

**Downsides of this method:**

- Lots of dynamic SQL, reducing performance and maintainability
- Pretty bad performance depending on the table sizes due to the creation of a temp table, and potentially from the CTEs?

---

From the research I've done so far, it seems completely possible to achieve this without the dynamic SQL as long [as you're not doing the filtering](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2017/02/26/pagination-sql-server-interview-question-week-111/), and also [if you only allow filtering on a single column](https://dotnetdaily.net/web-development/sql/fast-sql-server-stored-procedure-filtering-sorting-paging).

[This is the closest solution I've seen to what I'm looking for](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28842129/6046312), but it returns all rows from the table and does paging on the webserver instead of in the query. When I started thinking about how we could avoid all this messy dynamic SQL this was my first thought, but there are concerns about the amount of memory on our webserver not being able to handle the full size of some of these tables. Our application is deployed on servers provided by our clients, so we are fairly limited in how much memory we can request, hence why we want to only return the paged data and the total counts from the DB to the web server.

I've also found [the much nicer way to do this using Entity Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application), but that is unfortunately not an option for us.

Lastly, it would be really great if I could write one STP that would handle this logic for multiple queries, which appears to be almost achieved by the [`exec_with_paging`](https://www.itprotoday.com/server-side-paging-sql-server) STP mentioned in this article, but the link for it returns a 404. I'm guessing this may not be possible, but I just wanted to mention it in case someone has any ideas.

Thank you for any help/guidance!

Comment: If you have dynamic filtering, then there's not really any way to avoid dynamic SQL.  Every solution that removes dynamic SQL will rely on passing parameters for each column you will ever want to filter on in some way or other.  Also, this solution is wide-open to SQL Injection as it currently stands.

Comment: Also, I have a VERY similar solution to this that gets around some of the performance issues in what might appear to be a counter intuitive way.  I select ALL the data into a temporary table and THEN use the `OFFSET x ROWS` and `FETCH NEXT y ROWS ONLY` in the final step of the procedure.  If you are only dealing with thousands  (or tens of thousands) of rows then this can actually be more efficient, especially if your data all comes from a single table.

Comment: @RichardHansell Yeah that makes sense, I was thinking there might be no way to get it completely free of dynamic SQL. Also thanks for the warning about the injection attack! We are aware of that, so we sanitize on the webserver before passing params into the STP. I just double-checked to be sure, and an attempted injection will be passed in as string data, which then returns no rows because there aren't any values in the table that match that text. (e.g. `where Name = 'test or 1=1--'`)

Comment: @RichardHansell Ok thanks! If we can at least improve the performance that's something, so I'll try that out. Usually, it's 1k-100k rows, we've haven't gotten into the millions yet, so that could be perfect!